# Stream a single (continuously updated) image file, using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, twitch

I am trying to stream an image file to twitch -- the idea being that the file gets continuously updated.

using

```
ffmpeg \
    -re \
    -framerate 10 \
    -loop 1 \
    -f image2 \
    -i "/path/to/file.png" \
    -c:v libx264 \
    -preset superfast \
    -tune zerolatency \
    -pix_fmt yuv420p \
    -s 1000x1000 \
    -r 25 \
    -f flv rtmp://asdf.twitch.tv/app/asdf
```

the stream works initially, but after modifying and re-saving the file, twitch shows an error (`There was a network error. Please try again. (Error #2000)`) while ffmpeg keeps running without any error.

then, when I re-save the file once *again,* ffmpeg stops, with

```
[flv @ 0x7faa6201c200] Failed to update header with correct duration. 71.0kbits/s speed=0.659x
[flv @ 0x7faa6201c200] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
```

any ideas what's going wrong here?

---

**edit:**

`-stream_loop -1` does not seem to help, as I'm getting this now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The image2 demuxer aborts upon a read error which can happen if the read and write aren't atomic. Replace `-loop 1` with `-stream_loop -1` to use the generic looping code which will continue retrying upon failure.